# Scraping Price Giving Undefined Value

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I am trying to scrape the price (in this case $85) from drop.com (https://drop.com/buy/drop-mito-mt3-cyber-custom-keycap-set). I am having trouble getting the values as my code prints out nothing (undefined). I'm pretty sure it's directing to the correct div. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

[image: HTML Code]

```
$(".DropPageHeader__drop_info__2sS0I .Grid__gridItemInner__1hwGE div", html).first().each(function() {
        price = $(this).text().trim();
        console.log(price);
})
```

Comment: Be sure to check that in puppeteer you get the same HTML as in your browser. Doesn't this site require registration and login to browse?

Comment: Ah, yes it does. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Seems like a JS driven website.